# Redirect page in react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can i redirect the page in react's class component after performing submiting a form (like create a post, login etc...) ?
is there an equivalent to useHistory hook for class based component ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) prop.

```
this.props.history.push('/path to page');
```

If `history` prop is not available in your component, wrap your component with `withRouter`

```
export default withRouter(MyComponent);
```